# Passing parameter to Web User Control by a data storage method like Session, Viewstate, Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing, webusercontrol

I have a web user control (`OrderDefinition.ascx`) which has a dropdownlist (`ddl_CustomerCode`), which is populated by web user control's page_load function

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            ddl_CustomerCode.DataSource = OrderDefinitionData.GetCustomers();
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataTextField = "CustomerCode";
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataValueField = "CustomerName";                
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataBind();
         }
    }
```

In my default.aspx page I dynmically add this web user control

```
    Control x = LoadControl("Controls/OrderDefinition.ascx");
    Panel1.Controls.Add(x);
```

I want to pass parameter to this web user control from my default.aspx, and I come up with the idea of using a session or viewstate or cache to use. So now my default.aspx looks like

```
    Session["myParam"] = "customerNo1";
    Control x = LoadControl("Controls/OrderDefinition.ascx");
    Panel1.Controls.Add(x);
```

And my Page_Load will look like

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string myParam = Session["myParam"];
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataSource = OrderDefinitionData.GetCustomers(myParam);
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataTextField = "CustomerCode";
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataValueField = "CustomerName";                
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataBind();
         }
    }
```

The problem is I am not sure about the way I code above, Should I trust this architecture? Please clarify me if this is the correct way to pass a parameter to a web user control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other have suggested you can do this in your ascx:

```
    public string myParam { get; set; }
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataSource = OrderDefinitionData.GetCustomers(myParam);
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataTextField = "CustomerCode";
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataValueField = "CustomerName";                
            ddl_CustomerCode.DataBind();
         }
    }
```

Then do this in your ASPX:

```
WebControl1 x = (WebControl1)Page.LoadControl("Controls/OrderDefinition.ascx");
x.myParam = "customerNo1";
Panel1.Controls.Add(x);
```

Note the casting to your TYPE of web control when you instantiate your web control through the LoadControl function - its important to do this cast so that your properties and methods are accessible to you.

Answer (score 2):

You should create property(ies) in your user control and pass the value through it.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a public property in your webcontrol like

```
private int myid=0;

public int MyID
{
    set { myid = value; }
}
```

then set it on pageLoad of your user control. In your defaultpage.aspx you can access property like

```
myUserControl.MyId=32;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create public methods in the controls, and access them through the pages, simple. or also you can set the properties, you have both options.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Session` like that makes it extremely difficult to encapsulate your control properly and it is not very intuitive to use, since the `Session` key will not visible appear on the control (or through intellisense for that sake). Use parameters on the control as others here suggest.